# How to detect mobile safari browser in ios 7?

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, ios7

**What is the official method to detect mobile safari on ios7?**

For example:

```
 navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) 
 && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/) 
 && navigator.userAgent.match(/OS 7/)
```

Answer (score 22):

Try this (to detect iPod touch as well):

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod touch);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/iP(ad|hone|od)/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

Gives simple T/F.