# Buildfire: How to detect user device? iOS vs Android?

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps, buildfire

I was wondering if it was possible to see what device users are operating the App from either through angular or Javascript.
I am guessing there would be 3 states? Android, iOS, and PWA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible to use browser detection logic with JavaScript. Based on the browser you can determine which OS is being used. (Safari for iOS and Chrome for Android.)

See this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript) posting covers one way to accomplish this.

If you wish to detect if it's a PWA on iOS, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091090/ios-web-app-showing-content-only-if-the-application-is-standalone).

Comment: I understand that you can check the browser, but on iOS, there is the possibility of being in App or being in Safari.  I am trying to determine whether the user is operating from the PWA or the app from the app store.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that will tell you what platform the user is using.

```
                buildfire.getContext(function (err, result) {
                    if(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
```