# Open links in main Safari browser instead of WebView - PWA (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, safari, progressive-web-apps

I send an email with a link of my PWA website.
When I click on the link and say open with Safari it opens in the Safari webview.
[image]

[image]

The Safari webview however does not have an add to homescreen option like the native Safari browser does.
[image]

When I open the link with my native safari browser I get the ability to add to homescreen.
[image]
[image]

What can I do to open the link directly in the native Safari browser instead of the webview.
Alternatively is there a way to find out that I am in the webview instead of the native Safari browser to prompt the user accordingly?

Currently testing on iOS 14.2

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Gmail App to open the link so it is prompting you which browser that you want to open the link with.

To open the link directly into the Safari browser instead of the webview (assuming you have it set as your default browser under Settings), click on the "Default browser app" option below the Safari option.

It is currently not possible to detect and prompt the user accordingly, however you could play around with [window.navigator.standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11109628/11162595) to detect if the user is in the PWA or not.